# WPF DataGrid set selectedItem

Tags: wpf, datagrid, selecteditem

my problem is that I want to set the selectedItem (mark a row in a datagrid).
I've searched a lot and actually I hope there is a better solution instead of iterate through the datagrid.

my suggestion:

I have a Number with the value 3 and I want that the datagrid-row with the number 3 is marked.. 
I tried this one:

```
DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)gridErrors.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(gridErrors.SelectedItem);

        if (row != null)
        {
            ErrorInfo info = row.Item as ErrorInfo;

            var blubb = from c in this.objectsToSync
                        where c.Number == info.Number
                        select c;

            if (blubb != null)
            {
                gridCsvContent.SelectedItem = blubb;
                gridCsvContent.ScrollIntoView(blubb);
                DataGridRow rowContent = (DataGridRow)gridCsvContent.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(gridCsvContent.SelectedItem);
                rowContent.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
            }
        }
```

First I extract the DataGridRow where my Number is from (value 3)
then I havea  linq query where I get the object with the number 3.
Then I want to set the selectedItem but it's null afterwards.

Is there a solution where I not have to iterate through the datagrid..? 
Is there a way to set the selected item directly?

Thank you very much in advance!
kr

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you will have to iterate over the collection to match to existing data in a cell.

If you're using the MVVM pattern you could move this logic to the `ViewModel` and work on the underlying data directly. You can create a dependency property to bind the SelectedItem to. I think you'll still need an event in the code behind to call `ScrollIntoView` though.